# Preferred non-breakable space

Tags: spacing

Let's say I have a sentence like: "I will be at the beach from 4 to 7 this afternoon." and I want to add breakable spaces to prevent numbers from being isolated. So far, no problem, I could write something like: `I will be at the beach from~4~to~7 this afternoon`.

Now what if I'd like to say that I'd *rather* have a non-breakable space between `4` and `to`, but it's ok to remove it on emergency stretch if it doesn't fit then.

Is there a way to use "preferred" non-breakable spaces that will be honored only if there is no overfull lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may not be exactly what you want, but try

`\newcommand{\almostnonbreakablespace}{\leavevmode\penalty 9999 \space}`